# How to include jquery in nodejs app using webpack?

Tags: jquery, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

This is my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
        filename: './bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

this is my app.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = $;
global.$ = $;
require('jquery');
console.log('Hello from Webpack');
$('#serviceContainer').hide();
```

So when i run node app.js to start my node app, it is requiring jquery and it is throwing the below error.

```
 throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
```

So i need to know how to include jquery in nodejs using webpack. If anyone knows please help.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why do you need jquery in nodejs application? Nodejs runs in the backend where as jquery runs on the frontend. You are getting this error as it cannot detect any window i.e. browser window

Answer (score 0):

jQuery to be in the global context (window)

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

ProviderPlugin

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '$': 'jquery',
        'jQuery': 'jquery',
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

With nodejs you can create the server-side of your web application while jquery is a JS library which allows you to manipulate the DOM of a web page client-side so jquery must used on your HTML pages. Server-side, instead, you must create a simple http server that send to the client the correct html page.

Comment: Correct. What did you want to do with jquery?  Maybe there's another library that's right for you